# Can water that never touches food have a (non)kosher status?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, water

I recently read the OK "Kosher Spirit" magazine, including an [article](https://www.ok.org/kosherspirit/chanukah-5781/canned-vegetables/) about canned vegetables and kashrut concerns.

The article reviews the steps in the production of canned vegetables and details how cans are filled and sealed, and then cooked in hot water:

> The brine or sauce is poured into the cans with the
> prepared vegetables and sealed. The cans are then sent to be cooked in a retort. (A retort is a large pressure cooker filled with water.) This process kills the bacteria that cause food spoilage, allowing for the canned vegetable to be stored for long periods and remain fresh. At the end of the cooking process, the cans are cooled with cold water, dried, and labeled.

It appears, then, that the food inside the can never comes in contact with the water in the "retort."

Later, the article expresses a concern that

> Additionally, there are very large retorts that can process two products simultaneously and a plain vegetable product can be cooked at the same time as a pork and bean product. Even if they are processed in separate retorts, often the water used for heating or cooling the product is recycled between the lines.

But if the cans are sealed, why would that have any impact on the status on the water outside the can? Can water be milchig, fleishig or treif even when it has only been in contact with the outside of a package. Is there some other status (eg. "water that was used in the preparation of treif cannot be used for something kosher even though the water is not trief")? [secondarily, if, hypothetically, some actual treif got into the water, could one then not use that water for boiling sealed cans of kosher food?]

Is there, then, any other limitations on the use of this water for other purposes?

Is this impact on the water because there is only a single layer between the food and the water and not a double layer (I'm thinking of the "[double](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/32795) wrapping" that I have heard discussed when cooking kosher food in a non-kosher oven).

Side note -- I sent this question as a letter to the editor of the magazine and have not received any acknowledgment or response.

Comment: Consider water that was worshipped as Avoda Zara. You can't drink it. (That appears to answer the title of your post but not the body)

Comment: Consider the case where on two opposite sides of the same barbeque grill you cook a hamburger and cheese blintz without them actually touching. Does that seem more intuitively problematic? Why?

Comment: @DoubleAA it begs a different question -- would that water be non-kosher (could it make me have to kasher things I put it on, or put into it)? Or is it just forbidden for use?

Comment: Lechorah that massive basin of water would have נ"ט בר נ"ט (secondary transfer of tast) from the pork or whatever (pork to can, can to water). That's why there might be any effect despite the cans being sealed (but I don't know how נ"ט בר נ"ט works with different thicknesses). Even so, I don't know why that would constitute an issue, because by the time that ta'am reached the can of veggies it would be ta'am shlishi and mutar, all the more so the veggies themselves.